# Column doesnt exist in vlookup table error in APACHE POI

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, vlookup, excel-tables

I have an Excel file with named excel tables for `VLOOKUP` in a sheet.

I'm trying to get the `VLOOKUP` result in another sheet by referencing through the `Gender_lookup` table. I am using the formula `=VLOOKUP(TRIM(CLEAN([@[Gender ]])),Gender_lookup,2,0)` which takes `Gender` value from current row in my table and checks for corresponding `Gender` value in `Gender_lookup` table in another sheet. The formula is valid and working in excel.

I have also [raised an issue in bugzilla](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=63934) for reference with all attachments

I tried evaluating with `XSSFFormulaEvaluator.evaluateAllFormulaCells(workbook)` which gives me the exception:

```
org.apache.poi.ss.formula.FormulaParseException: The column  doesn't exist in table Gender_lookup
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.FormulaParser.parseStructuredReference(FormulaParser.java:821)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.FormulaParser.parseNonRange(FormulaParser.java:908)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.FormulaParser.parseRangeable(FormulaParser.java:498)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.FormulaParser.parseRangeExpression(FormulaParser.java:322)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.FormulaParser.parseSimpleFactor(FormulaParser.java:1548)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.FormulaParser.percentFactor(FormulaParser.java:1506)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.FormulaParser.powerFactor(FormulaParser.java:1493)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.FormulaParser.Term(FormulaParser.java:1867)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.FormulaParser.additiveExpression(FormulaParser.java:1994)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.FormulaParser.concatExpression(FormulaParser.java:1978)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.FormulaParser.comparisonExpression(FormulaParser.java:1935)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.FormulaParser.intersectionExpression(FormulaParser.java:1908)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.FormulaParser.Arguments(FormulaParser.java:1479)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.FormulaParser.function(FormulaParser.java:1352)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.FormulaParser.parseNonRange(FormulaParser.java:905)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.FormulaParser.parseRangeable(FormulaParser.java:498)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.FormulaParser.parseRangeExpression(FormulaParser.java:322)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.FormulaParser.parseSimpleFactor(FormulaParser.java:1548)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.FormulaParser.percentFactor(FormulaParser.java:1506)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.FormulaParser.powerFactor(FormulaParser.java:1493)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.FormulaParser.Term(FormulaParser.java:1867)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.FormulaParser.additiveExpression(FormulaParser.java:1994)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.FormulaParser.concatExpression(FormulaParser.java:1978)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.FormulaParser.comparisonExpression(FormulaParser.java:1935)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.FormulaParser.intersectionExpression(FormulaParser.java:1908)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.FormulaParser.unionExpression(FormulaParser.java:1889)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.FormulaParser.parse(FormulaParser.java:2036)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.FormulaParser.parse(FormulaParser.java:170)
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFEvaluationWorkbook.getFormulaTokens(XSSFEvaluationWorkbook.java:85)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.WorkbookEvaluator.evaluateAny(WorkbookEvaluator.java:271)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.WorkbookEvaluator.evaluate(WorkbookEvaluator.java:216)
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.BaseXSSFFormulaEvaluator.evaluateFormulaCellValue(BaseXSSFFormulaEvaluator.java:56)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.BaseFormulaEvaluator.evaluate(BaseFormulaEvaluator.java:110)
    at practcie.Vlookup.main(Vlookup.java:97)
```

Comment: The apache poi formula parser is not able parsing the structured reference `TableName` to be a reference for `TableName[#Data]`. If the formula would be `=VLOOKUP(TRIM(CLEAN([@[Gender]])),Gender_lookup[#Data],2,0)` then formula parser will succeed.

Comment: Hi Axel Richter, when i read the formula from apche poi it reads it as VLOOKUP(TRIM(CLEAN(Member_Data[[#This Row],[Gender mod]])),Gender_lookup[],2,0) ...Here Member_data is the name of the row table where i have written this formula and  Gender_lookup is  name of other table in 2nd sheet. i find nothing wrong in here..could u please elaborate on this once again

Comment: It is a bug in `apache poi`. The `Excel` formula `=VLOOKUP(TRIM(CLEAN([@Gender])),Gender_lookup,2,0)` is `=VLOOKUP(TRIM(CLEAN(Member_Data[[#This Row],[Gender]])),Gender_lookup[#Data],2,0)` when all structured references are fully given and the table having column `Gender` is named `Member_Data`. But `apache poi`'s formula parser gets `Gender_lookup` as `Gender_lookup[]`instead of `Gender_lookup[#Data]`.

Comment: Thank you so Much Axel it worked..But is there any alternate solution without alterning formula in excel through java